# Experimental (Panel) Data: combination of fixed and random effects for regression models

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am seeking your advice on regression models using experimental (panel) data. I have around 230 individuals who have participated in four rounds of an experiment.
The dependent variable is categorical (which complicates the analysis - simply OLS with clustered standard errors at the individual level cannot be used), while the independent variables are categorical and continuous.

My questions:

Can I combine the independent variable (`T_C` - whether the participant was assigned to the treatment or control group) (deemed fixed - as it does not change throughout the rounds) with the categorical variable risk (that indicates the riskiness and influences the categorical dependent variable - different in each round) and still have meaningful results?

I understand if I use `T_C` together with risk in a fixed effects model, `T_C` would simply drop out.

Any help or advice is highly appreciated!